# Connection Lost to Host upon attempting to join Dedicated Server hosted in Azure

Tags: hosting, satisfactory

I setup (or I am trying to setup) a dedicated server for Satisfactory.  It is running on an Azure hosted Windows 10 virtual machine.  I downloaded the dedicated server using SteamCMD and followed the guide found on the [Satisfactory Wiki](https://satisfactory.fandom.com/wiki/Dedicated_servers).

I am at the point where I enter the IP address of the server into the Satisfactory game client, and authenticate.  That part seems to work, as the screen correctly shows the information about the save game that the server loaded.  However, when I attempt to join, a loading screen briefly appears, and then I get a message saying that the connection to the host has been lost and I am retuned to the main menu of the game.

When I attempt to join (or my friend attempts to join), the server log shows some messages similar to that of [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/SatisfactoryGame/comments/rvmz8h/dedicated_server_issue/):

```
LogNet: Error: IsClientMsgTypeValid FAILED (40): Remote Address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1
[150]LogNet: Error: Failed to read control channel message ''
[150]LogNet: Error: UControlChannel::ReceivedBunch: Failed to read control channel message
[150]LogNetTraffic: Error: UChannel::ReceivedRawBunch: Bunch.IsError() after ReceivedNextBunch 1
[150]LogNetTraffic: Error: Received corrupted packet data from client ::ffff:127.0.0.1. Disconnecting.
```

What could be going on? I believe I correctly forwarded the necessary ports and configured the firewall appropriately as noted [here](https://satisfactory.fandom.com/wiki/Dedicated_servers#Port_forwarding_and_firewall_settings) in the guide on the wiki, so I am not sure what else could be happening.

Here are the ports as seen on Azure for the virtual machine:

[image]

**Update:**

I've tried using a Linux Virtual Machine instead (Ubuntu 20.04) and it results in the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue is **mods**.

After turning off all mods that I use (only two), I was able to connect to the server without issue.  I found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/satisfactory/comments/r40tw9/modded_dedicated_server/) that has a few comments claiming mods essentially don't work with dedicated servers yet.  One in particular quoted from a Discord Server (I believe the Official Satisfactory Discord, but the link in the Reddit doesn't work). The quote said:

> Dedicated servers:
>
> Here is the info about modding Dedicated servers!
>
> Will there be dediserver modding?
>
> Yes!
>
> When?
>
> The short answer is: we don't know.

So if you plan on joining a dedicated server and you are running into this issue connecting to them, you'll likely have to disable your mods if you have any.